# Excel filter for comma-separated values in a column based on values in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet with two columns G and H, such that -

| G | H |
| --- | --- |
| K0231, K0331, K0055 |  |
| K0003, K0044, S0203 |  |
| K0331, S0505 |  |
| K0005 |  |

I want to populate column H with only the comma-separated values in G which are present in the column A of Sheet2 that looks like -

| A |
| --- |
| K0002 |
| K0004 |
| K0231 |
| K0234 |
| K0331 |
| S0203 |
| S0505 |
| S0017 |
| K0408 |

such that column H looks something like this -

| G | H |
| --- | --- |
| K0231, K0331, K0055 | K0231, K0331 |
| K0003, K0044, S0203 | S0203 |
| K0331, S0505 | K0331, S0505 |
| K0005 |  |

I tried using the formula -

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(Sheet2!A:A), G2)), TRANSPOSE(Sheet2!A:A), ""))
```

but it doesn't give me the desired result. Can someone please help with correcting this formula or suggesting a different approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one option:

[image]

Formula in `H1`:

```
=MAP(G1:G4,LAMBDA(s,TEXTJOIN(", ",,REPT(A1:A9,ISNUMBER(FIND(A1:A9,s))))))
```

**Note**: Your sample output seems flawed.

Comment: Sample output corrected (missed the `S0505`). When using this formula, it shows me the error "The formula contains unrecognised text", possibly because of 's'.

Comment: As is the formula should work. Do you actually have the `MAP()` function available? This is an Excel 365 function. What version of Excel have you got? I see you did use `TEXTJOIN()`.... @harry04

Comment: @harry04 If you don't have M365, consider almost the same in cell `H1`: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",,REPT(A$1:A$9,ISNUMBER(FIND(A$1:A$9,G1))))` and copy down. Don't forget to adjust the range references and the sheets.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another alternative, ofcourse Excel Dependent :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H1</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER($A$1:$A$9,ISNUMBER(XMATCH($A$1:$A$9,TEXTSPLIT(G1,,", "))),""))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I1</kbd>

```
=ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER($A$1:$A$9,1-ISERR(SEARCH($A$1:$A$9,G1)),""))
```

---

Answer (score 2):

### Match Delimited Data

[image]

- The solutions are case-insensitive. Consider that the cases of the strings in the source column may be different than in the lookup column.

**Short: Returns the strings from the lookup column `A2:A10`.**

```
=LET(sd,G2:G5,ld,A2:A10,dl,", ",e,"",
BYROW(sd,LAMBDA(r,IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(dl,,
    XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(r,dl),ld,ld,e)),e))))
```

**Accurate: Returns the strings from the source column `G2:G5`.**

```
=LET(sd,G2:G5,ld,A2:A10,dl,", ",e,"",
BYROW(sd,LAMBDA(r,LET(
    s,TEXTSPLIT(r,dl),
IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(dl,,
    FILTER(s,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(s,ld)))),e)))))
```